# How do I escape <% %> block in grails scaffolding _form template

Tags: grails, escaping, scaffold

I'm trying to customize my `_form.gsp` generation by grails scaffold process.
I need to parse to final `_form.gsp` template a `<% %>` block.
Should be something like this in the `'renderEditor.template'` file:

```
private renderManyToMany(domainClass, property){
  def sb = new StringBuilder()
  sb << ' <% ${domainInstance}?.${property.name}.each { %>'
  sb << '  ---- some code here ---- '
  sb << ' <%}%>'
  sb as String
}
```

that would result in

```
<% AuthorInstance.books.each { %>
 ---- some code here ---- 
<%}%>
```

at `_form.gsp` file.

I've tried `'\'` but not work. I appreciate any help. I've not found any documentation about it.

Comment: I'am not sure if I understand your question and not sure what you are trying to achieve. Why don't you just install the templates using `grails install-templates` and modify them?

Comment: I have installed the templates and I am editing the `renderEditor.template` file.

Comment: Ok. You write what output you expect. Can you provide the error or output you currently get? Maybe describing the problem will help me to understand your question. Have you tried using the unicode `\u003C\u0025` instead of `<%`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the unicodes `\u003C\u0025` instead of `<%`. That will help. Find further unicodes on this [website](http://unicode-table.com/en/).